# am trying to print("_id") data which am getting from server

Tags: ios, arrays, mongodb, api, nsdictionary

For the following swift code

```
 self.cardDataArray = response.value(forKey: "card_list") as? NSArray
 print(self.cardDataArray!)
```

i got this output from server(API)

```
(
        {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 5978b5dadc336d0788a81c58;
        "stu_number" = 1234567812345678;
        "stu_status" = 1;
        "created_at" = "2017-07-26T15:31:38.874Z";
        "stu_id" = 5978b41ddc336d0788a81c57;
        "stu_number" = 1234;
        "default_status" = 0;
        "default_type" = 3;
    }
)
```

am trying to print "_id" from above code
but am getting error
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1a9ae6ca0) to 'NSString'

here is the code which i tried to print

```
let studentID = self.cardDataArray?.value(forKey: "_id") as! NSString
print(studentID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cardDataArray` is a Dictionaries Array so you must first take this dictionary and access to the key you need in this case "_id", try with this code

```
if let studentDict = self.cardDataArray?[0] as? NSDictionary
{
   print(studentDict.object(forKey: "_id") as? NSString)
}
```

**Updated**

```
for dictObj in self.cardDataArray {
    print(dictObj.object(forKey: "_id") as? NSString)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if am getting single object means this code will work because we gave cardDataArray?[0]
if we are getting more than one object how should we print "_id" ?

Comment: @ammateja you can cicle over your dicts array and print as the same, i can provide code in update if you want to

Comment: @Renier could you please provide the code in update. i got stucked here again

Comment: @ammateja check my updated answer, and let me know if solves your issue